# VBA in ACCESS. Trouble with ComboBox

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I have some *ComboBoxes* on my *FORM*. One of them have *items* as a result of SQL request from field ***PG*** `(cbPG.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT W_report.PG FROM W_report WHERE ......)` The size of the field is *byte*.

[After reqest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnKnc.png)

User can select one of the variant or can list several comma-separated (*2,4,5,7,11,13*).

[Correct value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2VLb.png)

The resulting ComboBox.value is used in a procedure similar to selecting pages for printing. Everything works correctly until changes are made to the event handler of *cbPG*. Then the values are automatically rounded (if one comma)

[wrong value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUWGx.png)

or an error *"The entered value is not appropriate for this field"* occurs (if a few commas) and I have to copy *cbPG* from the backup because I can't find a property that changes format of  ***cbPG.value*** to *byte*.

- *Here is part of program that use my ComboBox*

```
Public Function MnogoListov(str As String) As String
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim res As String
Dim listArr() As String
res = ""
ReDim listArr(Len(str)) As String
For i = 1 To Len(str)
If Mid(str, i, 1) <> "," And Mid(str, i, 1) <> "." Then
listArr(j) = listArr(j) & Mid(str, i, 1)
Else
j = j + 1
End If
Next
For i = 0 To j
If i = 0 Then
res = listArr(i)
Else
res = res & " OR W_report.PG = " & listArr(i) End If
Next
MnogoListov = res
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. A combobox is for selecting one value from several.

So, either use a *multi-select listbox* or a simple *textbox* where you - *similar to selecting pages for printing* - parse the inputted values to obtain the sequence (list) of items (pages).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought about switching to ListBox and TextBox, but I have about a dozen such forms - the transition will take time. In addition, ComboBox works in a real project as I described (similar to selecting pages for printing). To paraphrase the question: how do I make the format of each ComboBox element as String?

Comment: The return value from a combobox is always a string - even if it is a single digit.

Comment: VBA after loosing focus from ComboBox gives me an error if I put [1,2,3] in it or gives "1" if I put [1,2]. It looks like value become Byte. But I know that ComboBox.Value - String. I can't understand

Comment: As said, a combobox is not for multi-value input. One item only. In your case, one digit only.

Comment: This is link to 1 minute video to show how it works https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kPJiyTi1jkpkGNrNuGCigZTrEMfYnZat

Comment: I would use a textbox and then use Split to separate the inputted value(s).

Comment: Thanks for Split- implemented it in the program. I know that combobox is not for multi-value input. But I don't need it. I need a string entered by the user (if you watched the video, you should have seen it ). In the properties of ComboBox I set the following values: LimitToList  - No, allow changing the list of values -Yes, only the values of the string source -No.